# Allow Azure/Centos mongodb port

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to install a mongodb replicaset Azure Centos OS 7.2. Following this tutorial:
[azure mongodb docs](https://mongodb-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ecosystem/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows-azure.html), I've manage to get my tree centos instances up and running, with mongodb.

The problem is: I can't place a replicaset working. After struggling trying to make rs.initiate work using this json

```
{
"_id" : "mongors",
    "members": [{
        "_id": 0,
        "host": "mongodbrs.cloudapp.net:27018"
    }, {
        "_id": 1,
        "host": "mongodbrs.cloudapp.net:27019"
    }, {
        "_id": 2,
        "host": "mongodbrs.cloudapp.net:27020"
    }]
```

}

and getting errors saying that was not possible connect to any other instance but itself, I realize that my problem was before configuring a replicaset.

My VM's can ping each other, pinging their private ip. Telnet to port 22 (also using private network ip) is working fine.

**But any other mongodb port is not allowed.**
I got the network security group and inbound security rules set.

[image: Azure Inbound security rule]

Comment: I posted an answer, calling out an error in your inbound security rule, and thinking it was as simple as that. However, I then just looked at the tutorial you followed, which is *ancient* and I can't imagine how you could have possibly run that installer (there's actually no tutorial there, just an installer app). I really think you need to edit your question to show how you created the repl set, esp since your screenshot shows NSG rules from an ARM-based deployment, yet you're talking about a `yourname.cloudapp.net` Classic cloud service (which could also be related to your issue).

Comment: David, you're right. The first thing I did was to forget that tutorial and start from scratch. Using mongodb docs for installing, your answer and configuring a replica set also with mongodb docs, altogether did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your source port range. You need to make this a wildcard (`*`), meaning your traffic can *originate* from any port.

The target port is where you specify the port range where traffic is allowed to reach.

Answer (score 0):

Setup the source to 0.0.0.0/0 and * ports. It's not the better solution but will help you to understand if the problem is in network layer or not.